# Remove Special characters in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to remove the special characters from the file name. Please find the below code. I am have issue in removing the . from the file name, my code removes the .in the extension too.

```
Ex filename = atf.bac.xlsx
Expected result: atfbac.xlsx
Current Behavior:atfbacxlsx


NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".#%;:?,/|\[]{}@$%^*"];
fileName = [[fileName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to treat the string as a filename in a path or URL

- Save the file extension temporarily.
- Delete the file extension.
- Remove the unwanted characters.
- Add the file extension.

  ```
  NSString *fileName = @"atf.bac.xlsx";
  NSString *extension = fileName.pathExtension;
  NSString *baseName = [fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
  NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".#%;:?,/|\[]{}@$%^*"];
  fileName = [[[baseName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""] stringByAppendingPathExtension:extension];
  NSLog(@"%@",fileName);
  ```